# System.Collections.Generic vs System.Collections?

Tags: c#

I have read at couple of places that, a generic collection class in the System.Collections.Generic namespace should be used instead of classes such as ArrayList in the System.Collections namespace. I am not able to understand, how is it better, as both are collection?

Comment: generics one provides compile type safety

Comment: Generics were a later addition to the framework.  In general it means you can work with typed collections, rather than collections of objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generic collection types allow strongly typing your collections. Take for example this `ArrayList`, which we want to contain dogs:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.Add(new Dog());
```

If you want to get the first item out, you need to cast the result, since `Dog d = a[0];` doesn't work. So we do this:

```
Dog d = (Dog)a[0];
```

but the compiler also allows this:

```
Cat c = (Cat)a[0];
```

Generics allow you to do this:

```
List<Dog> a = new List<Dog>();
a.Add(new Dog());

Dog d = a[0];
```

See! No casting. We don't have to help the compiler understand there can only be dogs inside that list. It knows that.

Also, this won't compile:

```
Cat c = a[0];
```

So: no boxing and unboxing, no runtime errors because there is a wrong cast. Type safety is a blessing for programmers and users. Use generic collections as much as you can, and only use non-generic collections if you have to.

Comment: Thank you, now I am able to understand it more clearly.